# Equivalence Class Equality Proof

Tags: logic, equivalence-relations

Let ~ be an equivalence relation on the set $A = \{1,2,...,8\}$, and denote the equivalence class of $x ∈ A$ by $[x]$.

If $1 ∈ [3]$, $2 ∈ [4]$, and $1 ∈ [2]$, prove that $[4] = [3]$.

**Work So Far**

If $1 ∈ [2]$, $2 ∈ [4]$, then $1 ∈ [4]$

However, beyond this, I'm not sure where to go. I *do* have $1 ∈ [3]$ and $1 ∈ [4]$, but I don't see how to extend that into proving $[3] = [4].$ Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: For any equivalence relation, $a \in [b]$ if and only if $b \in [a]$ if and only if $[a] = [b]$. So you can immediately conclude that $[3] = [4]$ from what you've said.

Comment: Got it! So by that logic I can prove $[1] = [3]$ and $[1] = [4]$, meaning $[3] = [4]$. If you want the answer points I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any equivalence relation, $a \in [b]$ if and only if $[a] = [b]$. So in your case, $1 \in [3]$ implies $[1] = [3]$, and $1 \in [4]$ implies $[1] = [4]$. So all together, $[3] = [4]$.